# Removing all Related Products

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, products-management, product-relations

Long time reader first time poster.

I have about 1200 products in my Magento 1.9 store. I'd like clear out all of the existing Related Products (setting all products to have no relations). Is there an easy SQL statement I can run in MySQL that can do this? Or am I stuck either having to purchase a extension, or worst case -- gasp -- do i have to do it manually for each product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run this on your database.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE `link_type_id` = 1
```

but back-up your db first.

Comment: its not related to this question. just wanted your advice. Is there any document available which will precisely explain the table structure of Magento?