# Truncate Catalog_product_link

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalog

I want to know if i truncate `catalog_product_link`, Will it be filled again after reindexation ?
I'm trying to clean as some link between products are now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a generated index table. Truncate it and you'll have an empty table to refill. What do you mean the links between products are obsolete?

Comment: I mean that some products are no longer related but i think the link between them is still in the table which is become pretty big.

Comment: Truncate the table and you remove them all. The products still exist, you just don't want them related anymore?

Comment: Exactly. It would not affect products or their categories in any way ?

Comment: No, although I'd advise you to keep a back up anyway. See this answer here; http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/removing-all-related-products/31707#31707